# Magento 2.3.0 installation error

Tags: magento2, error, installation, fatal-error

I am trying to install magento 2.3.0 on localhost i am getting following issue.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in `/var/www/html/m230/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php` on line 35

Comment: Getting below error in installation 2.3.0 1st screen > Error: [$rootScope:infdig]
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$rootScope/infdig?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/142239)

Comment: Can you please add your PHP version? Maybe watch this issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17285

Comment: Can you please let us know if you are trying to install it via composer or Web wizard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Magento 2.3** is not supporting php **version 7.0**

it works with **php 7.1** OR **php 7.2**. It fully supports **php 7.2**.

Please check your php version and upgrade it to **php 7.2**(recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Check this official link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Check whether your system satisfies it's requirement as php 7.0 and php extensions.

In future mention which machine you are trying to deploy magento in your question description.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in requirement doc https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

**Magento v2.3.0** supports **PHP v7.1.3+** so any version higher than this will resolve your issue.

I tested it with **PHP v7.1.24** it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use 'php72' instead the 'php' and there would be no issues.

[image: php72]

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link
[After installing magento 2.3 admin login page cant open properly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252069/after-installing-magento-2-3-admin-login-page-cant-open-properly/252070)

```
Find : /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:139

find : 
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
        return true;
    }
}

Replace with:
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    $realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
    // and replace `$directory` with `$realDirectory`
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your magento version does not support your PHP version.

If you want to run it as 7.2 on ssh you should append the path to php 7.2 first and then php- command.

Open .htacess and add this line on the top of it 
SetEnv PHPRC /home/your directory/public_html/php.ini

So the system could know now php.ini path.

Now open CMD and execute any command with this /usr/local/bin/phpxx bin/magento c:c where XX should be your desired php version, for instance php72 or php71 etc

/usr/local/bin/phpxx bin/magento c:c this command clears the cache